# Image format for displaying document pages

Tags: image, image-processing, tiff

I was wondering what image format would be best suited to save document pages. (document pages are mainly text with few images). I know that png, jpeg are bitmap formats and hence they will have scaling problems. I don't know much about TIFF (tagged image format). Does it have an advantage over png/jpeg for document pages?

Comment: What exactly do you  mean by "scaling problems"?  Is this a problem no matter how high the resolution of the images?

Comment: @DarenW, I think he means in comparison to a vector format, PDF being the best example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TIFF can save [multiple pages per file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format#In_document_imaging), PNG and JPEG cannot. TIFF also has a number of different format choices for bit depth and compression, which might make it the best choice or might result in a nightmare depending on the compatibility of the different software components used. Avoid the JPEG compression option in TIFF, it has known problems.